# Is calling a constructor faster then setting a field Mono?

Tags: c#, c++, memory-management, constructor, mono

I'm working on implementing Mono to my C++ project and I have a C# class that holds a single integer. Something like this:

```
public class TestClass {
    int number;
}
```

And I have another Class that has a field of `TestClass`. Something like this:

```
public class AnotherClass {
    TestClass test;
}
```

Now, I have an instance of `AnotherClass` called `instance` and I want to set it's `test` field. Since the field can be null by default I create an instance of `TestClass` called `testInstance`, set it's `number` field and then set `instance.test` field to `testInstance`.

However I'm wondering if it wouldn't be faster to instead give `TestClass` a constructor that sets the `number` field to a parameter it takes and then initialize `testInstance` with that constructor and lastly set `instance.test` to `testInstance`. So my questions is that, Is it faster to call a constructor that just sets a field from withing C# or to set that field manually from within C++

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: I tried to test it however I'm wondering more about the technical side. On my side the results were essentially so small that I wasn't able to find a difference. However on a slower computer it might be way faster one way or other due to something technical about how mono works.

Comment: Is this an important part of your application or it is just a minimal aspect that will never do any difference on the perceived "speed" of your application on those "slow" machines?. It seems that you are just looking for ["premature optimizations"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: Before engaging in optimization for the sake of optimization, you need to **profile** your code before and after the optimization.  Sometimes well-intentioned but misguided hand-optimizations pessimizes the code.  If you don't measure (**profile**) the effect of the hand-crafted optimization you really don't know if you've made things better, or made them worse.  (Or made a negligible difference, but at the cost of making the code illegible.)

Comment: @Steve now that I think about it, it probably doesn't really matter. Since it's just setting a singular integer so I think I'm gonna leave it like this. However I wouldn't mind actually learning more about this problem just for knowledge sake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance difference should be very small in your case, It may be big when your constructor has complex code inside it or multiple fields to be set. In general, it's good to practise keeping the constructor simple and doing the object initialization inside it.

When you are setting the field directly not in the constructor you are escaping from doing the things which the constructor does apart from setting this particular field.

your code should be readable, easily maintainable and scalable, so chose the approach accordingly.

If you are really concerned about the performance then you could do a benchmark and compare the results.